# How to place an <aside> element 'aside' main content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been using various techniques to try and solve this problem I have. I'm creating another practice website (I.e. with no intention to publish) regarding self-help. I'm trying to place a side-bar containing quotes from people throughout history. But my aside element (the side-bar) won't appear alongside the main content.

I've tried placing the main content within a 'main' tag with the 'aside' element outside (I.e. separate containers), but even this doesn't work. I've tried using float:right and other techniques, but just cannot get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks...

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: garamond, serif;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.links {
  margin: 8px;  
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.links:hover {
  opacity: 0.30;
  width: 
}

header {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: orange;
  text-shadow: 8px 8px 16px grey;
}

#section1 {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#section2 {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

section p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#asideh2 {
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: justify;
  float: right;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Self-Help Emporium</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <a class="links" id="link1" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="links" id="link2" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="links" id="link3" href="#">Blog</a>
      <a class="links" id="link4" href="#">Contact</a>
      <a class="links" id="link5" href="#">Disclaimer</a>
    </nav>
    <header>
      <h1>Self-Help Emporium</h1>
      <h2>Your Trusted Source for Self-help Material</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <section id="section1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus, elit ut vestibulum maximus, orci felis pulvinar velit, malesuada faucibus est lacus et arcu. Cras commodo est nec venenatis blandit. Nullam pretium feugiat ultricies. Proin accumsan, mi et convallis ullamcorper, turpis leo pretium justo, non tincidunt mi est vitae purus. Aenean ultrices scelerisque lacus, eget sagittis justo consectetur ac. Vestibulum interdum consectetur nibh ut lacinia. Aliquam ac fringilla lacus, ut scelerisque purus. Nulla faucibus fringilla varius. Quisque enim ante, placerat eget semper vitae, pulvinar bibendum mi. Maecenas pulvinar tempus tellus, ut consectetur purus feugiat vel. Nulla eget viverra urna. Nulla eu ex eu nisi accumsan scelerisque. Nullam et nulla bibendum, condimentum odio eget, aliquet sem. Nunc ornare volutpat urna ut feugiat.</p>
        <p>Maecenas scelerisque leo ipsum, id molestie dui auctor ac. Nunc feugiat laoreet tortor et convallis. Duis quis nisl et libero consectetur bibendum tempor at lectus. Praesent tristique, mi semper pharetra fermentum, metus orci porta ipsum, sit amet accumsan dolor tellus sit amet magna. Nam iaculis odio vel gravida egestas. Vestibulum venenatis est non orci pharetra ultricies. Fusce urna leo, commodo a ex vel, cursus semper sem. Etiam rutrum at est ut volutpat. Etiam vitae ullamcorper lectus. Duis tempus maximus nisi, eu aliquet felis congue ut. Donec erat arcu, malesuada eu ligula quis, consectetur suscipit mauris. Mauris commodo tortor ac elit euismod facilisis.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum porttitor pulvinar erat finibus molestie. In at felis eu augue feugiat ullamcorper in ut sapien. Pellentesque gravida eros non sapien convallis ullamcorper. Vivamus magna odio, tristique sed sapien aliquet, dictum aliquet augue. Nunc lorem quam, rutrum quis nulla euismod, ornare aliquet urna. Nullam lobortis malesuada nisl, vitae mattis purus pharetra nec. Duis enim est, malesuada quis odio ac, rutrum luctus nisl. Morbi tortor risus, posuere quis orci ut, pulvinar luctus lectus. Mauris auctor risus ut dapibus mattis. Suspendisse euismod felis mauris, sit amet rhoncus lacus posuere et. In scelerisque lacus vel arcu pellentesque facilisis. Aliquam nisl tortor, cursus ac tincidunt luctus, malesuada quis lectus.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="section2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus, elit ut vestibulum maximus, orci felis pulvinar velit, malesuada faucibus est lacus et arcu. Cras commodo est nec venenatis blandit. Nullam pretium feugiat ultricies. Proin accumsan, mi et convallis ullamcorper, turpis leo pretium justo, non tincidunt mi est vitae purus. Aenean ultrices scelerisque lacus, eget sagittis justo consectetur ac. Vestibulum interdum consectetur nibh ut lacinia. Aliquam ac fringilla lacus, ut scelerisque purus. Nulla faucibus fringilla varius. Quisque enim ante, placerat eget semper vitae, pulvinar bibendum mi. Maecenas pulvinar tempus tellus, ut consectetur purus feugiat vel. Nulla eget viverra urna. Nulla eu ex eu nisi accumsan scelerisque. Nullam et nulla bibendum, condimentum odio eget, aliquet sem. Nunc ornare volutpat urna ut feugiat.</p>
        <p>Maecenas scelerisque leo ipsum, id molestie dui auctor ac. Nunc feugiat laoreet tortor et convallis. Duis quis nisl et libero consectetur bibendum tempor at lectus. Praesent tristique, mi semper pharetra fermentum, metus orci porta ipsum, sit amet accumsan dolor tellus sit amet magna. Nam iaculis odio vel gravida egestas. Vestibulum venenatis est non orci pharetra ultricies. Fusce urna leo, commodo a ex vel, cursus semper sem. Etiam rutrum at est ut volutpat. Etiam vitae ullamcorper lectus. Duis tempus maximus nisi, eu aliquet felis congue ut. Donec erat arcu, malesuada eu ligula quis, consectetur suscipit mauris. Mauris commodo tortor ac elit euismod facilisis.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum porttitor pulvinar erat finibus molestie. In at felis eu augue feugiat ullamcorper in ut sapien. Pellentesque gravida eros non sapien convallis ullamcorper. Vivamus magna odio, tristique sed sapien aliquet, dictum aliquet augue. Nunc lorem quam, rutrum quis nulla euismod, ornare aliquet urna. Nullam lobortis malesuada nisl, vitae mattis purus pharetra nec. Duis enim est, malesuada quis odio ac, rutrum luctus nisl. Morbi tortor risus, posuere quis orci ut, pulvinar luctus lectus. Mauris auctor risus ut dapibus mattis. Suspendisse euismod felis mauris, sit amet rhoncus lacus posuere et. In scelerisque lacus vel arcu pellentesque facilisis. Aliquam nisl tortor, cursus ac tincidunt luctus, malesuada quis lectus.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <form>
    </form>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <span>Mathew J. M. | 2018 ™</span>
      <span>Last updated: 11/09/2018</span>
    </footer>
  <aside>
    <h2 id="asideh2">Self-Help Quotes:</h2>
      <p>No matter where you are in life, you’ll save a lot of time by not worrying too much about what other people think about you. The earlier in your life that you can learn that, the easier the rest of it will be.</p>
      <p>Our only limitations in life are those we set up in our own minds.</p>
      <p>Focus on what you can control: your actions. How you react to negative feelings will be the key to your success.</p>
      <p>Don’t Take Anything Personally. Nothing others do is because of you. What others say and do is a projection of their own reality, their own dream. When you are immune to the opinions of others, you won’t be the victim of needless suffering.</p>
    </aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note that my overall website is placed within an 800px-wide container (I.e. like the BBC News website). I've tried reducing the aside to 50px-wide and the main container to 750px-wide (totalling 800px-wide), but this doesn't place both containers side-by-side either.

---

Update: 13th September

I have added 'display: flex' to the body of the document, as was suggested, and the aside column certainly has moved up, but it has disfigured the whole document. The heading is now at the left side and not at the top where it should be. The footer has also changed to become vertical and now skews text.

Can somebody help me put the header and footer elements where they should be? The footer should be at the very bottom. The header should be below the navigation bar at the very top (I.e. not where it is now). Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of the edit]

Comment: Are you wanting the aside next to main, or are you wanting a column with everything in and then the aside next to that?

Comment: I don't mind changing the syntax to match whichever method you think is best, Pete. I don't mind having the 'aside' within a primary container, or having 'aside' separate.

Comment: I'm not sure if I answered your question correctly. I wanted the 'aside' column next to the main content. But I don't want it 'fixed' in terms of position.

Comment: Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, naming an element `aside` does not tell the browser to move it to the side. `html` is the skeleton, `css` is responsible for positioning, layout and overall design if you will.

Technically, all you have to do is declare `display: flexbox` on a parent element:

```
main{display: flexbox;}

<main>
    <article>
    </article>
    <aside>
    </aside>
</main>
```

However, your original example also has some unclosed tags an unusual nesting of elements. Don't overthink it, keep things simple.

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: garamond, serif;
}

main{display: flex;}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.links {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.links:hover {
  opacity: 0.30;
  width:
}

header {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: orange;
  text-shadow: 8px 8px 16px grey;
}

#section1 {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#section2 {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

section p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#asideh2 {
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Self-Help Emporium</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <a class="links" id="link1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="links" id="link2" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="links" id="link3" href="#">Blog</a>
    <a class="links" id="link4" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a class="links" id="link5" href="#">Disclaimer</a>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <h1>Self-Help Emporium</h1>
    <h2>Your Trusted Source for Self-help Material</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <article>
      <section id="section1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus, elit ut vestibulum maximus, orci felis pulvinar velit, malesuada faucibus est lacus et arcu. Cras commodo est nec venenatis blandit. Nullam pretium feugiat ultricies. Proin accumsan,
          mi et convallis ullamcorper, turpis leo pretium justo, non tincidunt mi est vitae purus. Aenean ultrices scelerisque lacus, eget sagittis justo consectetur ac. Vestibulum interdum consectetur nibh ut lacinia. Aliquam ac fringilla lacus, ut scelerisque
          purus. Nulla faucibus fringilla varius. Quisque enim ante, placerat eget semper vitae, pulvinar bibendum mi. Maecenas pulvinar tempus tellus, ut consectetur purus feugiat vel. Nulla eget viverra urna. Nulla eu ex eu nisi accumsan scelerisque.
          Nullam et nulla bibendum, condimentum odio eget, aliquet sem. Nunc ornare volutpat urna ut feugiat.</p>
        <p>Maecenas scelerisque leo ipsum, id molestie dui auctor ac. Nunc feugiat laoreet tortor et convallis. Duis quis nisl et libero consectetur bibendum tempor at lectus. Praesent tristique, mi semper pharetra fermentum, metus orci porta ipsum, sit
          amet accumsan dolor tellus sit amet magna. Nam iaculis odio vel gravida egestas. Vestibulum venenatis est non orci pharetra ultricies. Fusce urna leo, commodo a ex vel, cursus semper sem. Etiam rutrum at est ut volutpat. Etiam vitae ullamcorper
          lectus. Duis tempus maximus nisi, eu aliquet felis congue ut. Donec erat arcu, malesuada eu ligula quis, consectetur suscipit mauris. Mauris commodo tortor ac elit euismod facilisis.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum porttitor pulvinar erat finibus molestie. In at felis eu augue feugiat ullamcorper in ut sapien. Pellentesque gravida eros non sapien convallis ullamcorper. Vivamus magna odio, tristique sed sapien aliquet, dictum aliquet augue. Nunc
          lorem quam, rutrum quis nulla euismod, ornare aliquet urna. Nullam lobortis malesuada nisl, vitae mattis purus pharetra nec. Duis enim est, malesuada quis odio ac, rutrum luctus nisl. Morbi tortor risus, posuere quis orci ut, pulvinar luctus
          lectus. Mauris auctor risus ut dapibus mattis. Suspendisse euismod felis mauris, sit amet rhoncus lacus posuere et. In scelerisque lacus vel arcu pellentesque facilisis. Aliquam nisl tortor, cursus ac tincidunt luctus, malesuada quis lectus.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="section2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus, elit ut vestibulum maximus, orci felis pulvinar velit, malesuada faucibus est lacus et arcu. Cras commodo est nec venenatis blandit. Nullam pretium feugiat ultricies. Proin accumsan,
          mi et convallis ullamcorper, turpis leo pretium justo, non tincidunt mi est vitae purus. Aenean ultrices scelerisque lacus, eget sagittis justo consectetur ac. Vestibulum interdum consectetur nibh ut lacinia. Aliquam ac fringilla lacus, ut scelerisque
          purus. Nulla faucibus fringilla varius. Quisque enim ante, placerat eget semper vitae, pulvinar bibendum mi. Maecenas pulvinar tempus tellus, ut consectetur purus feugiat vel. Nulla eget viverra urna. Nulla eu ex eu nisi accumsan scelerisque.
          Nullam et nulla bibendum, condimentum odio eget, aliquet sem. Nunc ornare volutpat urna ut feugiat.</p>
        <p>Maecenas scelerisque leo ipsum, id molestie dui auctor ac. Nunc feugiat laoreet tortor et convallis. Duis quis nisl et libero consectetur bibendum tempor at lectus. Praesent tristique, mi semper pharetra fermentum, metus orci porta ipsum, sit
          amet accumsan dolor tellus sit amet magna. Nam iaculis odio vel gravida egestas. Vestibulum venenatis est non orci pharetra ultricies. Fusce urna leo, commodo a ex vel, cursus semper sem. Etiam rutrum at est ut volutpat. Etiam vitae ullamcorper
          lectus. Duis tempus maximus nisi, eu aliquet felis congue ut. Donec erat arcu, malesuada eu ligula quis, consectetur suscipit mauris. Mauris commodo tortor ac elit euismod facilisis.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum porttitor pulvinar erat finibus molestie. In at felis eu augue feugiat ullamcorper in ut sapien. Pellentesque gravida eros non sapien convallis ullamcorper. Vivamus magna odio, tristique sed sapien aliquet, dictum aliquet augue. Nunc
          lorem quam, rutrum quis nulla euismod, ornare aliquet urna. Nullam lobortis malesuada nisl, vitae mattis purus pharetra nec. Duis enim est, malesuada quis odio ac, rutrum luctus nisl. Morbi tortor risus, posuere quis orci ut, pulvinar luctus
          lectus. Mauris auctor risus ut dapibus mattis. Suspendisse euismod felis mauris, sit amet rhoncus lacus posuere et. In scelerisque lacus vel arcu pellentesque facilisis. Aliquam nisl tortor, cursus ac tincidunt luctus, malesuada quis lectus.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <h2 id="asideh2">Self-Help Quotes:</h2>
      <p>No matter where you are in life, you’ll save a lot of time by not worrying too much about what other people think about you. The earlier in your life that you can learn that, the easier the rest of it will be.</p>
      <p>Our only limitations in life are those we set up in our own minds.</p>
      <p>Focus on what you can control: your actions. How you react to negative feelings will be the key to your success.</p>
      <p>Don’t Take Anything Personally. Nothing others do is because of you. What others say and do is a projection of their own reality, their own dream. When you are immune to the opinions of others, you won’t be the victim of needless suffering.</p>
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <span>Mathew J. M. | 2018 ™</span>
    <span>Last updated: 11/09/2018</span>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Serg. I will take what you've said into account and will get back to you on the results.

Comment: Serg, can you help me out here? I updated my question above. What you suggested worked, but it created another problem. I now need to re-position the header and footer elements. The header needs to be at the top (but below the nav bar) and the footer needs to be at the very bottom. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mathew1a in my example the header IS below the nav. You're doing something wrong on your end. The current issue is resolved. You need to accept my answer and create new threads for new problems.